# Can I skip CynanogenMod updates

Tags: cyanogenmod, updates, custom-roms

When I install the nightly updates for CyanogenMod, do I need to install every single update or just the last one?

Answer (score 0):

Just the last one. Simple as that.

However, if you do cross-Android-version updates (e.g. CM13 (6.0) to CM14 (7.0, coming soon)), it is *strongly recommended* to wipe and start over.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I know a bit more regarding updates :) @Andy Yan